# How to pass QueryDocumentSnapshot to another activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to open a new activity (from fragment) and pass an object of type `QueryDocumentSnapshot` with `Intent`. I'm familiar with the `putExtra` method but it does not accept `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. I saw this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents), and it said "If your Object Class implements Parcelable and Serializable then you can just cast". How do I know if `QueryDocumentSnapshot` can be casted? If it's not possible, what would be the way to do it (I can't implements `Parcelable` and `Serializable` because `QueryDocumentSnapshot` is not my class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick scan of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot) and the code it doesn't seem like `QueryDocumentSnapshot` or `DocumentSnapshot` are parcelable.

That means you'll have to store the data that you want to transport to another activity and that *is* parcelable into the extra. Typically this would be the snapshot's [data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot#getData()) and its [document ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getId()).

Comment: So I have to create a new class that implements `Parcelable`, pass the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` to the constructor, save it as a field, override the methods and that it?

Comment: That's one way to do it indeed. You could also just put the ID and data separately into the extra, for example by serializing the data to a JSON string, as strings are already parcelable.